# How to process a large amount of files without running in memory limit error?

Tags: php, laravel, console, laravel-artisan

I am trying to run this command and to zip ca. 11.000 files - I'm getting memory_limit error. The code below needs ca. 12GB from my memory_limit and it works only if i set the memory_limit to -1, but this is not a solution for me. Can anyone solve this problem? I added also the garbage collector, tried with unset(), sleep() but the script keeps adding to my php memory.

```
if ($this->argument('year')) {
                $startDate = Carbon::createFromDate($this->argument('year'), $this->argument('month'), 1)->startOfMonth()->startOfDay()->toImmutable();
                $endDate = $startDate->endOfMonth()->endOfDay()->toImmutable();
    
                $this->info('Fetching the tickets between '.$startDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s').' and '.$endDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
                $batchSize = 500; // Define the batch size
                $ticketsCount = Ticket::where('created_at', '>=', $startDate)
                    ->where('created_at', '<=', $endDate)
                    ->count();
                $this->line('<fg=blue>Total Tickets: '.$ticketsCount.'</>');
    
                if ($ticketsCount > 0) {
                    $this->line("\n<fg=yellow>Start building the .zip file.</>");
                    $pdfCounter = 0;
                    $totalBatches = ceil($ticketsCount / $batchSize);
                    DB::connection()->disableQueryLog();
    
                    for ($batch = 1; $batch <= $totalBatches; $batch++) {
                        $offset = ($batch - 1) * $batchSize;
                        Log::info('Batch: ' . $batch . ', Offset: ' . $offset);
    
                        // create .zip
                        $zip = new \ZipArchive();
                        $zipFilename = env('APP_ENV').'_tickets_archive_'.$this->argument('year').'_'.$this->argument('month').'_batch'.$batch.'.zip';
                        $zip->open($zipFilename, \ZipArchive::CREATE | \ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);
    
                        $tickets = Ticket::where('created_at', '>=', $startDate)
                            ->where('created_at', '<=', $endDate)
                            ->offset($offset)
                            ->limit($batchSize)
                            ->pluck('pdf_path', 'number')
                            ->map(function ($pdfPath, $number) {
                                return ['pdf_path' => $pdfPath, 'number' => $number];
                            });
    
                        $bar = $this->output->createProgressBar($tickets->count());
    
                        foreach ($tickets as $ticket) {
                            if (Storage::exists($ticket['pdf_path'])) {
                                $zip->addFromString($ticket['number'] . '.pdf', Storage::get($ticket['pdf_path']));
                                $pdfCounter++;
                            }
    
                            unset($ticket);
                            $bar->advance();
                        }
    
                        unset($tickets);
    
                        // Log memory_limit performance.
                        $this->line("\n<fg=yellow>Memory usage peak: " . number_format(memory_get_peak_usage(), 0, '.', ',') . " bytes</>");
                        $this->line("<fg=yellow>Memory usage end: " . number_format(memory_get_usage(), 0, '.', ',') . " bytes</>");
    
                        $bar->finish();
                        unset($bar);
                        gc_collect_cycles();
    
                        if ($zip->numFiles > 0) {
                            $zip->close();
                            // $zipFileContent = file_get_contents($zipFilename);
    
                            if (Storage::disk('local')->exists('ticket-archive/'.$zipFilename)) {
                                Storage::disk('local')->delete('ticket-archive/'.$zipFilename);
                            }
    
                            $fileHandle = fopen($zipFilename, 'rb');
                            $outputPath = storage_path('app/ticket-archive/'.$zipFilename);
                            $outputFileHandle = fopen($outputPath, 'wb');
    
                            if ($fileHandle) {
                                while (!feof($fileHandle)) {
                                    $chunk = fread($fileHandle, 8192); // Read 8KB chunk at time
                                    fwrite($outputFileHandle, $chunk);
                                    unset($chunk);
                                }
    
                                fclose($fileHandle);
                                fclose($outputFileHandle);
                            }
    
                            // Storage::disk('local')->put('ticket-archive/'.$zipFilename, $zipFileContent);
                            $this->line("\n<fg=green>Zip file created.</>");
                            unlink($zipFilename);
                            unset($zip);
                        } else {
                            $this->line(nl2br("<fg=red>No files found.</>"));
                        }
    
                        $this->line("\n<fg=blue>Total storage files for this month: ".$pdfCounter."</>");
    
                        $pdfCounter = 0; // Reset the PDF counter for the next batch
                        $this->line(''); // Add a new line for better readability
                        \Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::flushQueryLog();
                        gc_collect_cycles();
    
                        // Log memory_limit performance.
                        $this->line("\n<fg=yellow>Memory usage peak: " . number_format(memory_get_peak_usage(), 0, '.', ',') . " bytes</>");
                        $this->line("<fg=yellow>Memory usage end: " . number_format(memory_get_usage(), 0, '.', ',') . " bytes</>");
    
                        // Sleep for a few seconds (optional)
                        sleep(15);
                    }
```

Comment: you can use a streaming approach instead of loading all the files into memory at once

Comment: have you tried `$zip->addFrom()` instead of `$zip->addFromString()`?

Comment: OK thanks, but why it keeps adding to memory after each batch?

Comment: addFrom() is not recognized in \ZipArchive();

Comment: They probably meant `addFile()`.

Answer (score 0):

The trouble with the Zip format is that it is structured and indexed, which is not particularly stream-friendly. This means that most implementations do not actually *write* anything until the end, eg: `$zip->close()`. So every call to `addFromString()` necessarily must hold data in memory until the end.

Using `addFile()` addresses the memory issue, but requires that every file you want to add be written to disk, and exist until after `$zip->close()`.

You can get this done reasonably safely like:

```php
class TempFile {
    protected $name;

    public function __construct($dir='./', $prefix='tmp_') {
        $this->name = tempnam($dir, $prefix);
        touch($this->name);
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return $this->getName();
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        unlink($this->name);
    }
}

$tempfiles = [];
foreach ($tickets as $ticket) {
   // ...
   $t = new TempFile();
   $tempfiles[] = $t; // ensures that the objects don't go out of scope early
   file_put_contents($t, Storage::get($ticket['pdf_path']));
   $zip->addFile($t, $ticket['number'] . '.pdf');
   // ...
}
//...
$zip->close();
unset($tempfiles); // optional, but calls the destructors/deletes immediately.
```

This likely isn't going to blow your socks off performance-wise, what with all the disk I/O, but you could bolt on a sufficiently large SSD volume and set the temp dir to that to get more throughput.

While it *is* technically possible to write a Zip implementation that can stream, I'm not aware of one for PHP. There are also formats like TAR that are technically designed for streaming, but again the PHP implementations I've seen kind of drop the ball and use the same "all at once" batch workflow.